# RPM Lagging On Mazda 3 - 2008

Tags: mazda, rpm, mazda-3, egr

i have mazda 3 2008 with auto transmission.

after drive for 10-15 mintues the rpm get lagging. 
(when the lag start i lost a little performance on car :: pushing the pedal the rpm goes to 4000 but after a sec goes to 3700 without change the pressure on gas pedal)

Visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frEQPNeFoYA for check the video of this lag!

if i turn off the car for while the lag gone. but it become again after a long drive)

- i change the cylinder head but problem not solved.
- no error code.
- battery replaced
- i cleaned the throw body + MAF
- my mechanic said he cleaned the EGR too. but i'm not sure. it could be from there?

Q1:
do i need to replace the MAF or MAP sensor? ( no ODB error code )

Q2: 
could it be from transmission?

Q3: WHAT ABOUT KNOCK SENSOR?

this problem made me mad.

> UPDATE -> i change the knock sensor/o2 sensor but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you clarify the statement "*i change the engine but problem not solved*" ... You *actually* swapped the engine out?

Comment: i just change the cylinder head not the whole engine.

Comment: You say it goes down by 300, but in the video I see the rpm go down to idle speed. What is the clip showing actually? Is the rpm dropping while you hold the pedal at the same angle?

Comment: Before you start replacing sensors, connect a computer and see what the sensors show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem.
all the problem came from bad gauge Cluster :O

the official dealership replace my torque cluster and everything work perfect after the replacement

i bought the car for 60k and spend 20k for diagnosing jerking rpm.

Comment: i still don't know whats the connection between lost performance and display gauge.