# Throttle Body is not close/open smooth?

Tags: throttle, throttle-body

i have hesitate RPM . today i check my Throttle Body and i think is not close/open smooth. its feel lag when pressing pedal slowly. or its okay? what you think?

Visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVGk5Xc28Dg

**its electronic Throttle Body - Mazda 3 - 2008**

(i guess my problem coming from this. i'm not sure.)

> my problem:
>   [RPM Lagging On Mazda 3 - 2008](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/59599/rpm-lagging-on-mazda-3-2008)

Comment: This is a drive by wire system?

Comment: no its electronically.  it work with key on

Comment: That's what "drive by wire" means ;-) It is opposed to "drive by cable", which is directly attached to the gas pedal. No worries. Yes, it should be smooth. You might try shooting some lubricant directly onto the throttle blade shaft where it enters the throttle body on both sides. Don't use a lot, just enough to give it some lubrication. You might also see if you can tell if the shaft is bent or not, which could cause it to bind. When I say "bent", I mean tweaked somewhat, as I doubt it would be *really* noticeable.

Comment: Throttle Body replaced with new one. but still have lag in open/close.  is it normal? or its definitely a problem from somewhere else

Comment: after replacing with new TB i got another wired problem. when the engine reach to operation temp the (A/T) on and P0123 P233 come and the gas pedal get out of the radar . -- also is bad with my old TB --  (i will investigate and update this topic surly)

Comment: If there is a new issue (or separate), please ask a new question.